# The maximum value under the condition of complex constraint

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Let a<0, (3x^2+a)(2x+b)>=0 be permanent established on (a, b), and what is the maximum value of b-a?

Code 1

```
    MaxValue[{b - a, 
  a < 0 && (3 x^2 + a) (2 x + b) >= 0 && a < x < b}, {x, a, b}]
```

The result of the return is infinity, but the answer should be 1/3

Code2

```
    MaxValue[{b - a, 
  ForAll[{x}, a < 0 && a < x < b, (3 x^2 + a) (2 x + b) >= 0]}, {a, 
  b}]
```

But no return to the result.I want to know how to solve this problem by Mathematica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by minimizing the expression you want to be non-negative:

```
min = Minimize[{(3 x^2 + a) (2 x + b), a <= x <= b, a < 0}, x]
```

Which returns a piecewise function for the minimum value. One of the entries are
`1/192 (-1 - 48 a)` $\quad$ if $\quad$ `b == -(1/12) && -(1/8) < a < -(1/12)`

Within that case the optimal value for you problem can be found by constraining the minimum to be positive:

```
Maximize[{b - a,
          1/192 (-1 - 48 a) >= 0,
          b == -(1/12) && -(1/8) < a < -(1/12),
          a < 0}, {a, b}]
```

> ```
> {1/24, {a -> -(1/8), b -> -(1/12)}}
> ```

The code below does the same thing for all entries of the piecewise minimum:

```
opts = Map[
         Maximize[{b - a, #[[1]] >= 0, #[[2]], a < 0}, {a, b}] &,
         FullSimplify[min[[1, 1]], {a < 0}]];
```

The last case (`0` if `True`) of the piecewise minimum remains, but `True` is only correct given that all the previous conditions were `False`. Combining all the conditions we get:

```
lastCond = FullSimplify[Not[Or @@ min[[1, 1, All, 2]]], a < 0] && a < 0 // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> b == 0 && -(1/3) <= a < 0
> ```

Using that we can find the optimum within the last case and add it to the other:

```
opts = Append[opts,
  Maximize[{b - a, min[[1, 2]] >= 0, lastCond, a < 0}, {a, b}]]
```

There have been 2 kinds of error messages: Some contraints correspond to the empty set, which makes `Maximize` return `-∞`. Also sometimes the closure was used in order to return a maximum.

Below the emptyset optimizations are removed and the remaining are sorted:

```
SortBy[Select[opts, First[#] =!= -∞ &], N@*Minus@*First] // DeleteDuplicates
```

> ```
> {{1/3, {a -> -(1/3), b -> 0}}, {1/4, {a -> -(1/3), b -> -(1/12)}},  
> {1/24, {a -> -(1/8), b -> -(1/12)}}, {0, {a -> -(1/12), b -> -(1/12)}}}
> ```

and despite the closures that were taken, the largest optimum gives non-negativity:

```
Plot[(3 x^2 + a) (2 x + b) /. {a -> -(1/3), b -> 0}, {x, -1/3, 0}]
```

[image]